# Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
foreach ( $this->_defaultModel->getFields() as $field )
    $this->data['rowNew'][$field] = null;

    /*echo("defaultModel");
    debug($this->_defaultModel);
    */

    $this->data+= $this->_defaultModel->findAllByFields($search, $page, $limitPerPage, $orderBy, $order);
```

estou fazendo uma migração do codeigniter  `Unsupported operand types`

Foi alterado o padrão do operadores?

Comment: O retorno de `$this->_defaultModel->findAllByFields` é um *array*?

Comment: Não,é um objeto!

Comment: E qual seria o resultado esperado para uma operação "array + objeto"?

Comment: Transformei para array e continua o mesmo problema.

Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!

Comment: E como transformou?

Answer (score 1):

A variável `$this->data` é um *array* e o operador `+=` só funcionará quando o segundo operando também for um *array*.

```php
$data = [0];
$data += [1, 2, 3];

print_r($data);  // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Ou *array* associativo:

```php
$data = [0 => 'a'];
$data += [1 => 'b'];

print_r($data);  // [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']
```

Se o segundo operando não for um *array*, o PHP não saberá o que fazer e disparará o erro `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types`. Sendo assim, concluímos que o retorno de `$this->_defaultModel->findAllByFields` não é um *array*. Cabe a você verificar se deveria ser ou não.